# tle error in algorithm design

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

given binary string of size n ,there are two types of queries

1.D for input string D display longest subarray length of consecutive 1's

2.C X for input of string C and integer x change string position x to 1 if zero

**my attempt**

```
int main(){
    int n,k,i,j,y,count=0;
    string s,x;
    int maxcount=0;
    cin>>n>>k;
    cin>>s;
    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
        cin>>x;
        if(x=='D')
        {
            maxcount=0;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(s[i]=='1')
                {
                    count++;
                } else{
                    maxcount = max(maxcount,count);
                    count=0;
                }
            }
            maxcount = max(maxcount,count);
            cout<<maxcount<<endl;

        } else{
            cin>>x;
            s[x-1] = '1';

        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

**i think it could be done using offline queries ,can anyone suggest approach or solution**

Comment: You have something that looks awfully O(N^2) there. Competitions generally want you to know or seek out the "trick" that reduces the time complexity to something more managable

Comment: @user4581301 can you suggest me the approach

Comment: What would be the point of that? Then I win the competition, not you.

Comment: @user4581301 what do you think which competition it is its not from competition bro

Comment: Unrelated Recommendation: Avoid `endl` in code you want to run quickly. `endl` inserts an end of line and then flushes the stream to the underlying media. A flush can be grossly expensive, so you only want to do it what you absolutely have to. Prefer a simple `'\n'`.

Comment: @user4581301 sure any further help clue will be appreciated

Comment: `if (x == 'D')` shouldn't compile. Comparing `string` with `char` Neither should `s[x - 1] = '1';` Cannot subtract 1 from a `string` and cannot use a `string` as an array index. I think you mean for `x` to be a `char`

Comment: question is about designing of algorithm not pointing errors in code,btw code is working and its compiling fine

Comment: Then your compiler is broken: https://ideone.com/Q0YajF

Comment: There are some similar questions today. Homework or contest...

Answer (score 1):

You may use disjoint set data structure for your problem. Each substring of consecutive '1's will be one component. When you change some char '0' to '1', you may create a new set with this single element. There may be several cases:

1. prior and next char is '1'. So you can merge these three sets.
2. prior is '1'. You can merge this one with prior set.
3. next is '1'. You can merge this with next set.